# ... what is the greatest integer n for which f must be n times continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus

This question is #53 from the [GRE Math Practice Book](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf)

Let f and g be functions of a real variable such that $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(y)(y-x)dy$ for all x. If g is three times differentiable, what is the greatest integer n for which f must be n times continuously differentiable?

Comment: What have you thought about so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It is easier to differentiate $$g(x)=\int_{0}^x f(y)y\,dy - x\int_{0}^x f(y)dy$$

What is $g'(x)$? What is $g''(x)$? $g'''(x)$?

Comment: Hmm, I keep wanting to say that g'(x) = 0 by using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and basically replacing y with x in each of the integrands and dropping the integrals.  But then g would be infinitely differentiable.  That first integral must require some sort of substitution..?  Can you explain why or point me to some reading material for this?  Thanks

Comment: @Ben $x\int_{0}^x f(y)\,dy$ is a product of the function $x$ and the integral. You can't just differentiate the integral.

Comment: $$\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt\right)'=b'(x)f(b(x))-a'(x)f(a(x))$$

Comment: Ohh, [facepalm].  Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was a typo.